Enumerate all possible sign configurations of a series in order of the increasing sum
I have a question that I think is related to this one:
Algorithm wanted: Enumerate all subsets of a set in order of increasing sums
but I couldn't adapt it to my problem, which is:
Given a series $S = \pm x_1 \pm x_2...\pm x_n$, where $x_i > 0$, enumerate all possible sign configurations in order of the increasing value of $S$.
For instance, consider the series $[1,1,2,2]$:
\begin{align}
&-1-1-2-2 = -6\\
&+1-1-2-2 = -4\\
&-1+1-2-2 = -4\\
&+1+1-2-2 = -2\\
&-1-1+2-2 = -2\\
&-1-1-2+2 = -2\\
&+1-1+2-2 = 0\\
&+1-1-2+2 = 0\\
&-1+1+2-2 = 0\\
&-1+1-2+2 = 0\\
&-1-1+2+2 = 2\\
&+1+1+2-2 = 2\\
&+1+1-2+2 = 2\\
&+1-1+2+2 = 4\\
&-1+1+2+2 = 4\\
&+1+1+2+2 = 6\\
\end{align}
$n$ can be large, so it's infeasible to enumerate and sort all possible combinations. I've tried a few things but couldn't get around it.
Any ideas on what to search for? I'd greatly appreciate it!

I doubt that there's anything better in general than enumerating and sorting.
You'll have $2^n$ terms to enumerate, and sorting them will take something like
$n \; 2^n$ steps.
The alternative would be some way to generate the terms already sorted.  Of course you could do that if, say, lexicographic order (with $- < +$) turns out to work (which would be the case if $0 < x_{n+1} < x_n/2$).  But in general, I think it's unlikely that you could predict the next term in much less than $n$ steps (which is what it would take to beat enumerate-and-sort).
